# Finding explicit $\delta$ to show a function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^3$ has a local minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, defined as $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^3$.

We say that the function has a local minimum at a point $\mathbf{a}$ if for some $\delta > 0$ we have $f(\mathbf{a}) \leq f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in B(\mathbf{a},\delta) \cap X$ with $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

I want to show / find some sort of explicit $\delta$ that would work. This is what I've worked towards:

AFter doing the necessary differentiation we find that $(0,0)$ is the critical point.  So then this means I want to find a $\delta$ such that $f(0,0) < f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in B((0,0),\delta)$.

Playing around I have this relationship:   $x^2 + y^3 = x\cdot x + y \cdot y^2$   and I want this greater than $0$. To be in my ball means $\delta >\|(x,y) - (0,0)\| > |x-0|, |y-0|$ individually.

From here I thought about "controlling" my $x$ and $y$. So I said let $\delta = 1$ for the individual absolute values. Doing that I said let $\delta_1 = 1$ where $\delta_1$ was used for $|x - 0| < \delta_1$. Doing that we see $-1 < x < 1$. Using this idea in my comparison above, the condition that arises is $x^2 + y^3 > y^3$. So as long as $y > 0$ then $f(x,y) > f(0,0)$.

Doing this for $\delta_2 = 1$ where $\delta_2$ was used for $|y-0| < \delta_2$, we have $-1 < y < 1$. This leads to a the comparison $x^2 + y^3 \geq x^2 - 1$. Which I would want to be $x^2 - 1 > 0$ to satisfy the conditions of the function. With some tinkering I could get an alternate form, saying $|x| > \pm 1$ (which came from $|x|^2 = \sqrt{x^2}^2 = x^2$). So I could say that as long as $\delta_2 < 1$ and this condition of $|x| > \pm 1$ is upheld my function is satisfied.

But I'm a little confused because this isn't me finding an explicit $\delta$ that works. I'm kind of equating the process I went through to the one you would use if this was a first year $\delta-\epsilon$ sort of proof....

How else could I approach this?

Comment: This function does not have a local minimum at $(0,0)$. It is a saddle point. Plot it in calcplot3d to verify.

Comment: This function has a saddle point at $(0, 0)$ and no local minima anywhere, so it's hardly surprising that a search for delta is rough going.

Comment: Since for any reals, $y_1<y_2$ implies $y_1^3 < y_2^3$, you can't have a minimum.

Comment: Got clarification. Should I delete the question since it doesn't bring any value or keep it around for the sake of posterity?